# Cannot install php5-mysql in raspbian

Tags: php, mysql, raspberry-pi, owncloud

I have been trying to install php5-mysql in order to run an owncloud server, but every time I try it shows a dependency error, view it here:

```
    pi@raspberrypi:/var/www/html $ sudo apt-get install php5-mysql 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-mysql : Depends: libmysqlclient18 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am inputting the command sudo apt-get install php5-MySQL. I have looked for the dependency but so far haven't found it and tried to install it using synaptic but it shows the same error. Do I need to use something different as is this out of date or has been removed? The tutorial I am following to run owncloud on my pi is available [here](https://www.stewright.me/2014/06/tutorial-install-mysql-server-on-raspberry-pi/)

If there any detail I need to provide I will do so, I would just like to know how to obtain that dependency or a suitable alternative for owncloud on raspberry pi.

Comment: Literally the first search result for that error message ~ https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=193290

Comment: Thank you I am using a weird browser. Also it might be a personalised result.